# Global variable in C file that is acessed by multiple dlls

Tags: c, windows, dll, dllexport

I am working with a C windows application that contains multiple DLLs.  The first DLL defines a global variable that is used by multiple functions.  The second dll has a method that calls a function within the first dll, which in turn accesses that global variable.

When I access the global variable from the first dll, everything works fine, but when the global variable is accessed from a call that originated from the second dll, then I get the following error:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in a.exe
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Note: None of the functions in the second variable will ever access that global variable directly.  It will only be via calls in the first dll.

I have tried to export the variable via a .DEF file and then define the variable in the second dll with '_declspec( dllimport )', but that did not work (I didn't expect it to because the second dll isn't explicitly accessing the variable.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's the access of the variable that's causing the crash and not some other issue, like mismatched calling convention or something? What happens if you comment out the line of code that actually uses this variable?

Comment: I thought at first the calling convention issue could be part of the issue, but then I don't believe the code would link if it was.  If I comment out the line, it continues without an issue.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the help.  I finally realized that the issue was related to have two instances of the global var defined.  Some code paths were using the one that was properly defined and the other one was using a version that was not defined.